# How to stopEffect in Cocos2d via ALuint?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, effect, simpleaudioengine

Where is the soundId in Cocos2d?

I understand that it is returned from somewhere, but how do you capture this value or where it is?

I am trying to stop an effect using:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopEffect:<#(ALuint)#>];
```

But, I do not know where to get the soundId for said effect.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ALuint is returned from playEffect:

```
ALuint effect = [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"effect.caf"];
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopEffect:effect];
```